# array_multisort behaviour when comparing sub-arrays

Tags: php

Is this a bug in array_multisort, or can the behaviour be explained?

The code below

```
$a = array(
    "aa" => array("2" => "2"),
    "a" => array("1" => "1"),
);
array_multisort($a);
print_r($a);
```

Prints

```
Array
(
    [aa] => Array
        (
            [2] => 2
        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

If I change the key order of the param $a as below, the result printed also has a different ordering

```
$a = array(
    "a" => array("1" => "1"),
    "aa" => array("2" => "2"),
);
```

I would expect the output from array_multisort to be the same in both cases?

Comment: Well both subArrays have the exact same amount of elements and are therefor considered equal. And so the order is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

for numeric value in array use `array_multisort($num,SORT_DESC,SORT_NUMERIC);` use sort_numeric for sorting

Comment: My example does not specify any sort flags

Comment: check this tutorial (http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_multisort.asp)

Answer (score -1):

The comment posted by Rizier123 is the correct answer. The number of elements in the sub-array determines the sort order.

Using [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) instead of [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) in the example from the question will always produce the same results.